# Getting average using array and functions

Tags: c, arrays

In C language.
Hi how can I compute general weighted average using grades and units?
for example,
input grade = 1.25, 3.0, 1.0
input units = 3, 3, 3

then the output will be 1.25*3 +3.0*3 + 1.0 *3 then divided by 9 which is the total units.

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: C language poss

Answer (score 1):

In `PHP` here is the solution. Since language is not mentioned:

```
 $grade = [1.25, 3.0, 1.0];
 $unit = [3, 3, 3];
 $count = 0;

 foreach($grade as $key => $val){
   $count += $val * $unit[$key];
 }

 $divide = $count/array_sum($unit);

 print_r($divide);
```

Here in `C`. I don't know much about `C` but hope it helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float grade[] = {1.25, 3.0, 1.0};
float units[] = {3, 3, 3};
float sum = 0.0;
float count = 0.0;
int i = 0;
float division = 0;

int main()
   {
   for(i = 0; i < sizeof(grade)/sizeof(grade[0]); ++i){
      count += grade[i] * units[i];
      sum += units[i];
   }

   division = count / sum; 
   printf("%f",division);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. But I need it in C language.

Comment: this is helpful. Thank you

Comment: @Steele Glad to help :)

Comment: How to do Matrix Transposition in C language?Program will ask the user for the number of rows and columns and the data for the matrix. The output will be the transpose of the matrix.

Comment: @Steele You have to store it in an array. And then using the keys you can transpose it.

Comment: @Steele You can google it. There are various examples out there.